# javascript calculate price and view it immediately after i insert a number in form (input type='number')

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function

How can i  to calculate a price and show it immediately after I insert a number in my form ? I try this but the it shows me the price after i press submit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var price = document.getElementById("number").value * 5;
        return price;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction();
</script>

<td>
    <input type="number" name="numberofpages" id="number" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nrpagini'])){ echo $_POST['nrpagini'];}else{ echo '';}?>">
</td>
<td id="demo"></td>
```

When i insert a number in form I want to multiplicate numberofpages with 5 and show me immediately the price.Thanks!

Comment: a answer which use jQuery can be usefull for you ?

Comment: What function of jquery i should to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/L1jujE9fMRA4ygmiesmf?p=preview) that you can use as an example. I removed the PHP code and hardcoded a starting value since you can't use PHP in Plunkr.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function(){
          updatePrice();
          $('#number').change(function(){
              updatePrice();  
          });
      });

      function updatePrice() 
      {
        var price = $("#number").val() * 5;
        $("#price").html('Price = ' + price);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <label>Number of Pages</label>
      <input type="number" name="numberofpages"  id="number" value="1000" />
      <label id="price"></label>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can start the calculation on every key up with this :

```
$("#number").on("keyup", myFunction2);

function myFunction2() {
    $("#number").attr("value", $("#number").attr("value") * 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is in native Javascript:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/ue4y53j9/)

JS:

```
document.getElementById("number").onkeyup = function () {
    var price = document.getElementById("number").value * 5;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = price;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="numberofpages" id="number" value="1">
<div id="demo"></div>
```